# ImageminPlugin with CustomWeback in Angular doesn't work in production

Tags: angular, webpack, build, imagemin

```
// webpack.config.js
const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default


module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ImageminPlugin({
      pngquant: {
        quality: '50' // unreasonably low value to see it works
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

```
// angular.json
"architect": {
  "build": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./webpack.config.js"
      },
    }
  },
  "serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
    "options": {
      "customWebpackConfig": {
        "path": "./webpack.config.js"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine in development but when I run the application in production:

```
"start:prod": "angular-http-server --path dist/event-io -p $PORT",
"build:prod": "ng build --prod --stats-json",
```

the image has its original size even though the plugin is actually loaded.

Is there a problem with order?

Comment: I assume you build before you serve right?

Comment: Yes is that a bad thing? Shouldn't the build create `dist` folder with compressed images and and serve the compressed images?

Comment: No that is a good thing :-) It shows the order the other way around, hence the question. This should work fine - you’re not seeing any build errors? What happens if you do a build without —prod flag?

Comment: Oh wait.. shouldn’t you being using the .test with ImageminPlugin? You should give it a path or regex to tell it what to minify no?

Comment: That is a good point because my svgs stopped working. I will try that and let you know. :)

Comment: That didn't help but it fixed the problem with svgs.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think so.